# kafka Manager CMAK does not support java 8 anymore

Tags: java, java-8, yahoo-kafka-manager

I am looking to install kafka Manager tool,
I already have installed:

- Kafka version 3.1.0
- openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
- The Java_HOME is:

~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.322.b06-11.el8.x86_64/jre

When I see official Yahoo Kafka Manager , it require Java 11+
https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK

But I have Java 8

I found an old git repository supporting Java 8:
https://github.com/BonnierNews/kafka-manager

in the tuto, Again, if java is not in your path, or you need to run against a different version of java, using the following :

```
$ PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64/bin:$PATH \
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64 \
  /path/to/sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64 clean dist
```

But is it that this cmd with change the java path and will affect the infrastructure installe ????

How is it possible to install kafka Manager ?
is it ok if I install both java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely update Java.

Having both on your system is fine, but Java 8 will soon be end of life, and will not get security patches, potentially leaving your system to be vulnerable to exploits.

I would not recommend running old forks of CMAK only to workaround your need to use an older Java version

> this cmd with change the java path and will affect the infrastructure installe ????

No. Those variables are only used for that sbt dist command

Alternative solution would be to run CMAK in Docker

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I wonder If I add java 11 the kafka, hadoop and other installed technologies will not work anymore

Comment: how can I work with both java version and To define the location of Java 8 or Java 11;

Comment: Indeed java 8 is not dying , btw all my big data infrastructure is based on version 8

Comment: Hadoop, Kafka, etc all now support (and recommend) Java 11 in the latest versions of them. Maybe even Java 17 too (I know Kafka does)... Java 8 is definitely already dead. You can support both with setting `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64` while running CMAK, using SystemD, for example, or as mentioned, use Docker and don't need Java on your host at all

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,  if I set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-11-amd64 while running CMAK, while that mean that the default java version is 11?

Comment: Not default, no. Only for that process invocation